# Summaries categorical data in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with about 1567 entries that consist of numerical and categorical data. I would like to extract only the categorical data without showing duplicates

```
df <- data.frame(
  aninimal = c('cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog'),
  fur_col = c('tan', 'tan', 'tan', 'white', 'black', 'black', 'white', 'brown', 'brown'),
  age = c(2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 3, 1, 6, 5))
```

I used the following code but it gives me the whole list of categories that include duplicates

```
 summary <- df %>% 
group by (animal, fur_col) %>% 
summarize (animal, fur_col)
```

it gives me:

| anim | fur |
| --- | --- |
| cat | tan |
| cat | tan |
| cat | tan |
| cat | white |
| dog | black |
| dog | black |

the result I want is:

| anim | fur |
| --- | --- |
| cat | tan |
| cat | white |
| dog | black |
| dog | white |
| dog | brown |

Comment: `unique(df[,1:2])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  distinct(aninimal, fur_col)

  aninimal fur_col
1      cat     tan
2      cat   white
3      dog   black
4      dog   white
5      dog   brown
```

Or, if you wanna make it dynamic:

```r
distinct(df, across(where(is.character)))
```

---

In base R, use `unique`:

```r
unique(df[sapply(df, is.character)])
```

Answer (score 0):

additional solution option

```r
df <- data.frame(
  aninimal = c('cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'dog'),
  fur_col = c('tan', 'tan', 'tan', 'white', 'black', 'black', 'white', 'brown', 'brown'),
  age = c(2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 3, 1, 6, 5))

library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  expand(nesting(aninimal, fur_col))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   aninimal fur_col
#>   <chr>    <chr>  
#> 1 cat      tan    
#> 2 cat      white  
#> 3 dog      black  
#> 4 dog      brown  
#> 5 dog      white
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>